# give parameters to function and load the function the right way

Tags: python, function, arguments

i´m new to python and new to programming. Maybe you can help me with the following:

i have 2 files: warmaker.py and functions.py

I have 2 questions.

1. When i use the argument -i for inputfile, how can i handover the value of this variable (e.g. test.zip) to my function unzip()?
2. How can i call the function the right way?

**warmaker.py**

```
def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hi:o:d", ["help", "ifile=", "ofile="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        functions.usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            functions.usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in '-d':
            global _debug
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            global ifile
            ifile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            global ofile
            ofile = arg

    functions.unzip(ifile)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[2:])
```

**functions.py**

```
import os
import zipfile
import sys

def usage():
    print "\nHow to use warmaker.py"
    print 'Usage: ' + sys.argv[0] + ' -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> '


def unzip(ifile):
    print 'Before' + ifile
    ifile = os.path.splitext(ifile)[0] + ".zip"
    print 'after' + ifile
    print 'Changing extension from ' + ifile + 'to ' + ifile
    print '\nStart to unzip ' + ifile
    print " ..."
    extract = zipfile.ZipFile(ifile)
    extract.extractall('.')
    print ifile + 'successfully extracted'
    extract.close()
```

Maybe you can help me?

Kind regards

Comment: Inheritly all imported modules own the calling parameters via `sys.argv` there for `getopt` will have access to it. Also you're passing `ifile` as a parameter to `unzip()` so it should already get the parameter it needs. What's your error message in this case? Maybe I read this to quickly on the phone.

Comment: Pls look on my answer below. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In warmaker.py, you have

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[2:])
```

change it to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The options start from sys.argv[1].

sys.argv[0] is the name of the Python file.

Comment: ok thx. But i got the same errors. As you can see here `root@osboxes:~/PycharmProjects/warmaker# python warmaker.py -i CS_A3.war 
Before
after.zip
Changing extension from .zipto .zip` the ifile variable is stil empty. but why?

Comment: Thats strange! On my system, the above code works when i change the 2 to 1 in the sys.argv[2] line. Have you changed the code since you posted this?

Comment: No i didnt changed it. I now changed it to main(sys.argv[1:]) and deleted the blank line between `        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            global ofile
            ofile = arg

    functions.unzip(ifile)` . After that it worked. Strange. Now it variable ifile is passed corretly. Now i just have to look for the file with that name and try to unzip it. i think i can find a solution on overstack that for. Thx guys

Answer (score 0):

This is the output on the console:

```
root@osboxes:~/PycharmProjects/warmaker# python warmaker.py -i CS_A3.war 
Before
after.zip
Changing extension from .zipto .zip

Start to unzip .zip
 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "warmaker.py", line 33, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[2:])
  File "warmaker.py", line 30, in main
    functions.unzip(ifile)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/warmaker/functions.py", line 17, in unzip
    extract = zipfile.ZipFile(ifile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 756, in __init__
    self.fp = open(file, modeDict[mode])
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.zip'
```

As you can see, after the word "Before" there have to be the value of varibale "ifile" but there isn´t

Comment: The variable `ifile` is an empty string `''`in the unzip function, which prints as an empty string without quotes, and thus it is not visible. Your argument parsing routine is not working the way you intended. print the value of `ifile` in the main routine, just before you call `functions.unzip()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd edit it to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) (that's the main api reference; it also has a link to the more beginner-friendly tutorial right near the top) instead of optparse, because the docs say optparse is deprecated.

You have things set up to use a main function & a if __name__ == '__main__'  idiom, which is good, but it's not really needed here so I simplified things in my edit. If you put the warmaker.py code together in w/ the functions.py code in a single file (aka module), then you'd want to use if __name__ == '__main__' so that you could import the functions w/out the code you have in warmaker.py's main function running, but like this it's fine w/out too

*warmaker.py*

```
import argparse
import functions

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--ifile')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--outdir', help='specify the output dir. default is . (ie, the cwd)')
args = parser.parse_args()


if args.outdir:
    functions.unzip(args.ifile, outdir=args.outdir)
else:
    functions.unzip(args.ifile)
```

*functions.py*

```
import os
import zipfile
import sys

def usage():
    print "\nHow to use warmaker.py"
    print 'Usage: '
    print 'python ' + sys.argv[0] + ' -i <inputfile> -o <output directory (optional)>'
    # note that in python, if you concatenate a string then print it, you have to add the space chars yourself


def unzip(ifile, outdir='.'):
    print 'Unzipping', ifile
    prev_content = set(os.listdir(outdir))
    print " ... "
    with zipfile.ZipFile(ifile) as efile:
        efile.extractall(outdir)
    added_content = set(os.listdir(outdir)) - prev_content
    print ifile, 'successfully extracted'
    # calling print on variables separated by commas prints them separated by a space by default
    print 'extracted contents:'
    for n, name in enumerate(added_content):
        print n+1, name
```

Also, I changed it to where you can specify an output directory instead of file & I added a little code to show what new file(s)/dir(s) have been added, along the lines of what I thought you were going for. Giving an output file didn't seem to quite match up w/ what the docs on ZipFile say you can do w/ extractall method. If this is a custom usage that only operates on zipped single files & needs to work that way, you'll need to change functions.py substantially

Overall, this is pretty solid code for somebody new to programming though. Nice work

Comment: @yefpie you're welcome. If my answer helped, please consider upvoting or marking it the accepted answer, or let me know if you still have questions! :)